# Get value inside nested object using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following bit of code

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.d.results.length; i++) {
    console.log($scope.d.results[i]);  
}
```

which returns this:

[image]

I would like to get the value of the Name field out of this object but I can't think of the syntax to get at it. I've tried a few things with no luck. Can someone explain how to dig down 2 levels and get at it? Thanks!

Comment: `$scope.d.results[i].Name`

Comment: Can you offer that as the answer? I would have sworn up and down that I had tried that and it didn't work. But I just put it back in with success. Thank you Tushar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
$scope.d.results[i].Name
```

As, `$scope.d.results[i]` returns an object which contains the `Name`, you can use above syntax to get it from the object.